# How to look for elements in a set that satisfy a certain condition on the element itself?

Tags: python, hash, set

I have a set in which every element is a tuple of 2 tuples, each of the tuples contains itself 3 elements/fields, for example an element of the set would look like:

```
(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1'))
```

I need to look for specific fields of the elements of the set.
The way i do this now is:

```
            for set_element in my_set:
                s0 = set_element[0]
                s1 = set_element[1]

                if s0 == '('q0','l0','s0')':
                     "add this set_element to another set"
```

Now this works, but with a really high number of elements of the set I don't find this very efficient because every time I have to iterate through all the elements of the set and I can't exploit the efficiency of sets.

Is there a more efficient way to to this? Consider that i may also need to access to just one specific field like 'q0'

edit:
I'll make a more detailed example, let's assume I have this set of elements:

```
 x= [(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1')),(('q0','l1','s0'), 
('q1','l2','s2')),(('q0','l0','s4'),('q1','l1','s1')), 
(('q2','l2','s2'),('q3','l3','s3')),(('q4','l4','s4'),('q5','l5','s5'))]
```

and that i want to extract all the elements in which the first tuple has q0 as a element, so in this case the result would be

```
(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1'))
(('q0','l1','s0'),('q1','l2','s2'))
(('q0','l0','s4'),('q1','l1','s1'))
```

Comment: You could try using a set comprehension to aggregate all the required elements. Then just update "another set" with this aggregated set.

Comment: Could you give me a simple example of how would you do that?

Comment: Can you provide some data (doesn't have to be large, just more than one element) so that we can benchmark? Believe it or not, creating test data is the type of manual work which reduces responder-interest!

Comment: @jpp Yes sure. I added it in the question so that it's easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may see a ~30% speed improvement by using a set comprehension instead of an explicit loop:

```
x = [(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1')),
     (('q0','l1','s0'),('q1','l2','s2')),
     (('q0','l0','s4'),('q1','l1','s1')), 
     (('q2','l2','s2'),('q3','l3','s3')),
     (('q4','l4','s4'),('q5','l5','s5'))]

x = x*100000

def original(x):
    res = set()
    for set_element in x:
        s0 = set_element[0]
        if s0[0] == 'q0':
            res.add(set_element)
    return res

def jp(x):
    return {k for k in x if k[0][0] == 'q0'}

%timeit original(x)  # 110ms
%timeit jp(x)        # 77ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary instead of a tuple of a tuple, since you are only comparing the first item in the tuple pair, we can use that as a key, and use the second element in the tuple as the value. Then you can simply take advantage of the dictionary look up speed.

```
x = [(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1')),(('q2','l2','s2'),('q3','l3','s3')),(('q4','l4','s4'),('q5','l5','s5'))]

d = {a:b for a,b in x}

if ('q0','l0','s0') in d.keys():
    print(d[('q0','l0','s0')]) # or do something like adding it to another set
```

Note this only works if the first element of the tuple pairs are unique. If they aren't you have to slightly change how the dictionary is created, by checking if the key exist, and if it does then create a list of values instead, but this is getting off topic and just speculating details.

If you only need to search `q0` you can simply iterate through each keys, and checking if `q0` belongs to said key. You won't be able to get around this unless you flatting your tuple and have a list of values as a key:

```
for each in d.keys():
    if 'q0' in each:
        print(d[('q0','l0','s0')])
```

If this isn't what you are looking for then dictionary might not be the solution for you. You could also store the key as only `q0` for going the whole outer `for each in d.keys()` but once again it's up to your requirements and you said you need to be able to search `('q0','l0','s0')` and `q0`.

Comment: This could be an option, but let's say I need to extract all the elements that have the the first field equal to 'q0'  no matter what l and s are, how would I deal with that?

Comment: I see, iterating through all the elements of the dictionary and check for a condition is exactly what I would like to avoid because I have a really big set of elements. What would you use instead of dictionaries?

Comment: a database of some sort then, could be pandas could be an sql database. but if you want quick access to large dataset, that's what databases are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these methods if you want:

```
x= [(('q0','l0','s0'),('q1','l1','s1')),(('q0','l1','s0'),
('q1','l2','s2')),(('q0','l0','s4'),('q1','l1','s1')),
(('q2','l2','s2'),('q3','l3','s3')),(('q4','l4','s4'),('q5','l5','s5'))]

print(list(filter(lambda x:x[0][0]=='q0',x)))
```

second

```
def recursive(data):

    data1 = data[0]
    if data1[0][0] == 'q0':
        print(data1)
        return recursive(data[1:])


print(recursive(x))
```